# Same class in different project, multi-project view

Tags: phpstorm

I have update PhpStorm to *v2016.3.2* and now I can have added multiple projects to *Project* tool window.

Problem is that when I try to `Ctrl+click` on some class that is located in both projects IDE does not look only in project, but in all projects and shows *Multiple Implementations* note (*Note:* Class is unique per project).

[image: Different projects]

Also looks like PHP functions documentation shows same *Multiple implementations* note. One in actual PHP dir, other in PhpStorm plugins dir.

[image: PHP Native]

How to solve these issues?

Comment: AFAIK it's expected behaviour when you open multiple projects this way -- as one of the reasons of opening them like that is to be able to edit them in one window and have classes/functions available in main project as well. You may mark such unwanted folders and "Excluded" .. but that may defeat the purpose of opening projects like that (it actually depends on what you will exclude and why you need them opened like that .. but should work in general).

Comment: If you need proper isolation your other option (as far as I'm aware) is to open them in separate windows/frames.

Comment: P.S. Consider removing `php` tag -- I often see down voting for purely IDE-related questions with that tag present.

Comment: Consider following this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get any updates from JB devs: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33965